# The best way to transfer information from class to class in c#

Tags: c#, class

I got question, what is the best way to transfer information from class to class. I mean, I tried with return strings, where I have 3 items in listbox and they are named e.g. `Easy` `Normal` and `Hard` and then strings are named as items. It didn't work well for me, because than I loaded method, he returned me the string, but I cant use this in other class. Im doing it like this, by creating first in the first class:

```
if(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Easy")
{
return "Easy";
}
```

And then, in second class:

```
if(class.string1() == "Easy")
{
Do something.
}
```

It doesn't work. Do you guys can maybe help me? Or this question is too newbie, and I have to learn and search more.

Comment: Looks rather noob.  Rather then returning a string I suggest returning an Enum.  Also, you could pass the class with the info into the class which does not have it, then access the info from the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to utilize enumerations rather than "[magic strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string)". They are type safe and less error-proned. You can convert a string to an enum as well which lends itself well to your problem:

```
    public enum DifficultyEnum {
        NULL,
        Easy,
        Medium,
        Hard
    }

    public DifficultyEnum GetDifficulty() {
        var difficulty = DifficultyEnum.NULL;
        var selItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Enum.TryParse<DifficultyEnum>(selItem, out difficulty);
        return difficulty;           
    }
```

Then in your other class:

```
    swtich (classInstance.GetDifficulty()) {
        case Easy:
            break;
        case Medium:
            break;
        case Hard:
            break;

        case NULL: /*Hopefully you don't get here but be defensive and expect that somehow they'll manage to do so =P */
            break;
    }
```

**Edit:**

This is an issue of preference but you can also make the `GetDifficulty()` into a property instead like so:

```
    public DifficultyEnum Difficulty {
        get {
            var difficulty = DifficultyEnum.NULL;
            var selItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Enum.TryParse<DifficultyEnum>(selItem, out difficulty);
            return difficulty;           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking a few different questions here.

How you transfer information between classes depends on the type of classes you are using and the type of data you want to transfer. The simplest way to share data is probably to have a method that provides the data (either as return values, reference parameters, or a class returned that contains the data).

Beyond that, you need to be more specific about what "doesn't work" means. I can see it would work assuming it's set up correctly. However, it's not very efficient because comparing strings requires comparing each character in the string. It would make more sense to define an enum.

```
public enum Difficulty
{
    Easy,
    Normal,
    Hard
}
```

And compare it like this:

```
if(classInstance.Difficulty == Difficulty.Easy)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Of course, your class will need to determine which list item is selected and convert it to an enum.

Comment: The only issue I take with the answer is that it you don't address how to convert the string from the ViewState of the ListBox (in the OP's original code) back into the enum. Otherwise I'll upvote :)